# How do I open multiple sites randomly?

Tags: c#

I use this code for open sites. when I say "open google" it'll open google :

```
if (r == "open google")
{
    Process.Start("https://google.com");
}
```

now, how can I open multiple sites randomly ? I mean, when I say what's up it open one of these sites randomly : http://www.pcmag.com , https://www.ehow.com ...

i tried this code before but my software opened all sites :

```
if (r == "what's new" || r == "what's up")
{

    Process.Start("http://www.pcmag.com");
    Process.Start("https://www.ehow.com");
    Process.Start("http://www.zdnet.com");
    Process.Start("http://www.empireonline.com");
}
```

Comment: Place them in an array, then generate a random number between 0 and one less than the size of the collection and then access the location denoted by that random number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static void OpenRandomSite()
{
    var sites = new [] 
    {
        "http://www.pcmag.com", 
        "https://www.ehow.com", 
        "http://www.zdnet.com"
    };

    var rnd = new Random();

    Process.Start(sites[rnd.Next(sites.Length)]);
}
```

Your code will be like this:

```
switch(r)
{
    case "open google":
        Process.Start("https://google.com");
        break;

    case "what's up":
        OpenRandomSite();
        break;
}
```

Comment: thanks - just one thing, i want to open those random site with my voice ( i'm using speech recognition in my software ).                                                                                                                                          if (r == "what's new" || r == "what's up")
                {
                    Process.Start(OpenRandomSite());
         }                                                                                                         r means= record - when i use process.start it show me an error that can't convert void to string . how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a random url:

```
public List<string> Sites = new List<string>()
{
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.yahoo.com",
    "http://www.somethingelse"
};

Random randomizer = new Random();

public string RandomSite()
{
    int r = randomizer.Next(Sites.Count);
    return Sites[r];
}
```

Usage is self explained: `RandomSite()` will return a random url from your collection.